# Why is my audio no longer working after disconnecting HDMI?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

Recently when I connect my laptop with Windows 10 to my tv through HDMI and then disconnect it, I no longer have any sound until I restart my computer.

I have tried restarting the audio service in services.msc, uninstalling and reinstalling the audio drivers, all to no avail. I have the problem whether trying to use the laptop speakers or external speakers through the 3.5mm jack.

Comment: after you disconnect the HDMI cable, what is the default playback device? in win10 the easiest way to look is to RClick the speaker icon in the notification tray, select "Sounds" (to display the old more functional sound settings applet) and then switch to the "Playback" tab.

Comment: It goes back to the Speakers (Realtek(r) audio), like normal.